# AlarmClock provider change existing alarm

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-contentprovider

I'm using the [AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock) content provider to setup alarms.

The problem is that it creates a new alarm each time if the hours and minutes are not the same.
Is there a way to simply replace the old alarm?

I don't want to use `AlarmClock.ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM` because it doesn't work with `AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI` and opens the alarm app (some even don't support it at all).

Is it possible to avoid AlarmManager?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Some Alarm");

startActivity(intent);
```